# Sorting a DataGridView by DateTime

Tags: sorting, datagridview

I have a website that is written in asp.net using C#. grdStatus is an instance of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView. It displays 2 columns -- StatusDate and Status. StatusDate contains DateTime values. Status contains strings. The problem is that when the grid is sorted on StatusDate, it does not sort the values as DateTimes. Honestly, I'm not quite sure how it's sorting them. When I click on the Status Date column header, it sorts the dates like this:

```
Status Date
9/24/2014 10:01:06 AM
9/24/2014 10:00:58 AM
9/23/2014 7:27:23 PM
9/1/2015 4:48:35 PM
10/22/2014 12:15:38 PM
10/22/2014 12:15:29 PM
10/22/2014 12:12:52 PM
10/22/2014 12:12:27 PM
```

It's certainly not sorting them by DateTime, but it doesn't seem to be sorting them alphabetically, either. Here's the method that refreshes the grid. I added the two lines indicated by ---> in an attempt to force it to sort the rows by DateTime, but they seem to have no effect.

```
private void RefreshGrid()
{
    IEnumerable<OrderService.OrderDetailStatus> statusItems = services.OrderSvc.GetStatusHistoryForOrderDetail(OrderDetailId);
    IEnumerable<ViewModels.StatusHistoryGridViewModel> gridItems = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ViewModels.StatusHistoryGridViewModel>>(statusItems);
    grdStatus.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    grdStatus.DataSource = gridItems.ToDataTable<ViewModels.StatusHistoryGridViewModel>();
--->grdStatus.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
--->grdStatus.Sort(grdStatus.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

Here's the view model that's being used as the data source for the grid. As you can see, CreatedDate (which is mapped to StatusDate) is a DateTime member.

```
namespace IVGOffice.ViewModels
{
    public class StatusHistoryGridViewModel
    {
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've looked at some other posting related to this, but I haven't found anything that helps. Can anyone explain to me how to get this to sort correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem was that I was overlooking that fact that one of the dates had a different year from the others. After I noticed that, I was able to get the control to sort the column by the date; however, I still wasn't able to get it to sort by both date and time. I think this may be a bug in the DateGridView control. I replaced it with an UltraGrid control from Infragistics and that worked correctly.